# What is wrong with this Jade Plant? (Yellowing Leaves, Spots, White powder)

Tags: jade, fleshy-leaves

I own a jade plant which has been having some trouble recently. Before I start I will tell you that I water the plant once a week or sometimes even every other day if the soil is  dry. The plant sits on a windows sill, it gets lot of light but quite little direct sunlight since it is hidden behind some wooden panes. Around a week ago I decided to repot it into a slightly bigger pot but that didn't seem to help, the new pot has better drainage and some rocks at the bottom.

Now onto the symptoms, The bigger leaves are getting yellow and pale and drooping downwards. The leaves don't look nice, they have spots and other marks on them. I also noticed some white powdery stuff on the leaves and stem.

Here are a bunch of photos since my explanation wasn't too great:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am begging to think that it has a nutrient deficiency since for the 2-3 years that I have owned it I never fertilized it. But at the same time that wouldn't make sense since I just repotted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of this plant's problems can be resolved by changing some habits

- the plant is getting too much water, water once a week or when the leaves are starting to wrinkle
- not enough light, move right against the window
- ensure there is drainage from the bottom of the pot
- rocks do not go in the bottom of the pot as this does not help drainage but instead creates a [perched water table](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/13775/499)

When you repotted the plant the root system needs time to grow into the new soil but it is too wet.

Comment: Ok thank you, thats not where the plant is actually, its right up at the window usually, I just moved it down to take photos

Answer (score 1):

I’d say that it is powdery mildew which is a disease of the foliage, fruits, flowers and stems.

This is caused by s fungi and is usually caused by water stress: too much or not enough... too much in your case looking at the leaves.

This disease has a narrow range so what you have there should only affect similar plants.

The only real way to deal with this is to use a fungicide containing triticonazole or tebuconazole.

That will do the trick.

It is very important to follow manufacturer’s instructions and to use chemical responsibly.

Comment: Ok thank you for the answer, you were talking about water stress, I water this plant when the top 1 inch of soil is dry, and that can sometimes be every other day. Is that too much?

Comment: Also can I use any fungicide or one meant specifically for succulents?

Comment: @Mihkel it depends on your atmospheric conditions and compost. These should have very free draining compost. They are not cacti’s but they follow the same regime. I’d say it’s too much watering and the compost is not free draining. Add lots of horticulture grit. Tiny little stones.

Comment: @Mihkel most fungicides will treat powdery mildew. Check the instructions, some have added nutrients to help the plant recover. It is a foliage spray for easy treatment. Target affected part of the plant