# Brown/Black spots on Jade Plant leaves

Tags: leaves, succulents, jade

I noticed some brownish spots on a couple of my jade plant leaves? Is this serious? I water the plant once ever 6-10 days depending on the weather (When the soil is dry). The plant gets lots of indirect light and a couple of weeks ago I fertilized it with some cactus/succulent specific water soluble fertilizer. [image]

[image]

If you are wondering why the jade has so little leaves it is because it used to look like this: [What is wrong with this Jade Plant? (Yellowing Leaves, Spots, White powder)](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/39652/what-is-wrong-with-this-jade-plant-yellowing-leaves-spots-white-powder)

I decided to pick off most of the damaged/yellowing leaves and let the plant start over. I know its probably not the best choice but the plant has been doing significantly better and is growing very fast.

Comment: Considering where it was in comparison to where it is now I would be hard pressed to believe this is worth worrying about.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the spots are hard to see on the pics (both are WAY too dark), but it could be scales. If it's a recent development (appeared in the past week or two) try rubbing it off with a cloth dampened with isopropyl (or rubbing) alcohol or ethanol (ethyl alcohol). If it wipes off, be on the lookout for scale insects (especially at the bottom of the leaves) as they are particularly hard to get rid of once they appear. If it doesn't wipe off at all, it might be just a scar tissue. Just be gentle with the leaves as even completely healthy jade plant leaves break off rather easily.

Answer (score 1):

I am certainly not a plant connoisseur, however I do know Jades are very durable. I've had my girl for exactly seven years.
My tip to you would be to water only once a month even every two months no lie. They hate to get their feet wet.
That's what I do and she keeps growing and growing it's wild.