# What to do for the young avocado plant with brown spots on its leaves?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, fruits, avocado

I've read the answers to two similar questions but as the answers were opposing, i couldn't be sure what action to take. Here is what I have:

Here (Figure 1) is my Avocado plant, which i had potted with no leaves (it had rooted in water), 1.5 month ago.

[image: Figure 1: Avocado plant.]

Brown spots started to occur on the oldest leaves and now they are spreading through the younger ones. Here are some photos of the brown leaves.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Figure 2: Brown leaf.] | [image: Figure 3: Brown spot detail.] |

Now I will give information about the other conditions of the plant.

**The soil** I use seems me a little strange but the seller had told me that she also planted an avocado with this soil. It looks a little reddish, and it is a light media. You can see the soil below.

[image: Figure 4: Soil media.]

It has some white, salt like things in it, probably the minerals.

[image: Figure 5: Minerals in the soil.]

Here is the information on the soil package.

[image: Figure 6: Soil information.]

It is in a clay **pot** (but dyed), with a single hole at the bottom. I had also put some stones at the bottom for drainage.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Figure 7: Pot.] | [image: Figure 8: Pot hole.] |

I **water** the plant rarely, when the soil dries like 3-5 cm, or, when the leaves bends slightly.

It stands near a **north-east** facing window.

I couldn't decide if the cause is too much fertilized or poor fertilized soil.

Waiting for your suggestions, thank you :)

Edit: 15.03.2019,

It's getting worse. Vermicompost and changing to a normal soil didn't work. I had also taken the plant to the south-east window for more sunlight.

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: the plant] | [image: closeup of leaf] | [image: closeup of leaf 2] |

Comment: Is the soil you used actually potting soil, in other words, meant to be used for plants growing in pots?

Comment: Yes i guess, It says "for seeds, garden plants, pot plants (this what you mean i think), vegetable gardens, greenhouses and tree seedling as base".

Comment: Not sure what this is - doesn't seem to be fungal in origin. Is there anything under the leaves, especially on the other side of the visible brown spots?  The soil in the pot looks dry - how much water do you give it when you do water?

Comment: The photo shows under the leaves actually. Brown stains seem lighter at the top. Like they are occuring at the back but also visible from the top.

Comment: I am not sure how much water I give, because I use a big watering container. Probably like a glass of. You are right the top of the soil is dry. But ı feel like this is because the soil type. It is a loose media and surface dries fast. When I put in my finger like 1-2 cm, ıt ıs pretty wet. (the top surface doesn't get wet even right after I water it, because soil is soo loose and water goes down without going to sides.) Do you think it is from water, wouldn't the leaves bend if it was?

Comment: The stones in the bottom of the pot are not necessary and can actually cause what's known as a perched water table. Apart from the soil appearing too dry, I don't really know what those spots are - if the soil was too wet, it might have been anthracnose. Possibly a build up of salts in the soil, maybe...

Comment: An agricultural engineer in my neighborhood told me that it is zinc deficiency, and gave a vermicompost liquid. He told me to use it once in 15 days. Also advised me to change to a normal potting soil..

Comment: I hope vermicompost won't make it worse.. I didn't know that putting stones could be harmful, i will read about it, thanks for mentioning. And thank you very much for your kind help :))

Comment: I'd agree about the normal potting soil... it doesn't need anything special really.

Comment: Actually the reason i had used that soil and the stones was this thing I read:

Comment: "Good drainage is key to good growth ... If fully saturated for more than two days, the roots will rot and the plant will die. **Loose and sandy, but fertile soil that provides excellent drainage is important.** Ask for a light potting soil, like a mix for cactuses, at your garden centre. To help drain excess water away, you can also lay some stones at the bottom of the pot before filling it up with soil." [link] (https://www.avoseedo.com/successfully-growing-avocados-in-a-pot/)
It is really hard to trust what you found in the web when it comes to plant care..

Comment: see here https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/13774/what-is-a-perched-water-table

Comment: I'm glad to learn about this phenomena. I understand that it is a static balance between the hydrostatic pressure and water holding ability (capillary pull) of the soil. Though, i couldn't get why would the gravel **cause** the perched water table, I read your comment on the "pore size change" issue but I feel like it wouldn't affect. 

However I can see now that drainage has nothing with the gravel. If it's gonna drain, it can drain without the stones too. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the brown spots are on the leaves. That isn't soil though - looks like coco coir. If the avocado seed is only in coco coir, then the roots are struggling to find nutrients, as coco coir isn't used for nutrients.

If it were me, I'd replace it with some proper organic seed-raising mix - get one that's soft and fluffy to the touch. If it's chunky or dry/crumbly in any way, don't use it. Then add maybe a teaspoon of vermiculite on top (spread evenly - this helps to retain moisture).

Then give it a good amount of water - when water starts coming out the bottom of the pot, that's when you should stop watering.

And add some woodchips/mulch on top of the soil as a cover (don't use any dyed mulch though and don't use mulch that's been treated with chemicals, and especially don't use mulch that's come from a diseased tree). The cover of mulch acts as a blanket to keep the soil moist, and protects from the harsh sun. Notice in nature how it's always covering the soil? If there are no twigs, branches, leaves, etc. - then nature will use grass or weeds to cover the soil. We as human beings are so stupid that we think we're doing plants and trees a good thing by exposing the soil and letting it dry up. Good woodchips or mulch as a covering helps tremendously - and each time it's watered, it will basically release some of the nutrients in the woodchips/mulch into the soil. That's why forests do so well - they don't need any fertiliser from any companies, they just use twigs, branches, woodchips/mulch basically.